# Python: Image.frombytes() arguments

Tags: python

So I have a file **test.dat** which contains data for an image. The first two bytes are the width, the second two are the height, and then the rest of the file is the pixel data. How do I read this file and create the image?

This is what I have tried:

```
with open('test.dat', 'rb') as file:
    width = struct.unpack('H', file.read(2))
    print width
    height = struct.unpack('H', file.read(2))
    print height
    image = Image.frombytes('L', (width, height), file.read())
```

Printing width and height gives me the values I am expecting. However, I get the following: **TypeError: an integer is required.** Playing around with this, I noticed that if I just type in **(640, 480)** instead of **(width, height)**, it works well (I know that my dimensions should be 640, 480). So it seems that passing the width and height as they are is causing the error, because they are not integers, but shorts.

Therefore, I tried changing the **H**'s to **i**'s in the unpack function, to try to read two bytes of data and convert it into an int. However, this gives me the same error as before.

What's going on here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct.unpack` returns a tuple:

```
In [85]: struct.unpack('H', struct.pack('H', 640))
Out[85]: (640,)
```

Therefore, you could use

```
width = struct.unpack('H', file.read(2))[0]
```

(note the `[0]` at the end) -- but there is a simpler way which unpacks both `width` and `height` with one call to `struct.unpack`.

`struct.unpack` returns a tuple because it can unpack many values at once. For example, the format string `'2H'` indicates the second argument represents 2 unsigned shorts:

```
In [89]: struct.unpack('2H', struct.pack('2H', 640, 480))
Out[89]: (640, 480)
```

Therefore, you could simplify your code using

```
width, height = struct.unpack('2H', file.read(4))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working now. But I'm a little confused as to why this returns a tuple - in what circumstance would this return more than one entry in the tuple?

Comment: Good question. It leads to a simplification of your code (see above).