# Cant receive from my server image

Tags: python, image, sockets, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to send a image from my server to my client.

```
import socket
from PIL import ImageGrab

SERVER_PORT = 80

SERVER_SOCKET = socket.socket()

SERVER_SOCKET.bind((socket.gethostname(),SERVER_PORT))

SERVER_SOCKET.listen(2)

clientname , clientadress = SERVER_SOCKET.accept()

img = ImageGrab.grab()
data = img.tobytes()
clientname.send(data)


clientname.close()
SERVER_SOCKET.close()
```

Then I tried to get the image from the server to the client:

```
import socket
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import Image

my_socket = socket.socket()

my_socket.connect((socket.gethostname(),80))


data = my_socket.recv(4000)
data_img = Image.frombytes(data)

print(data)
```

It didn't work.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Did it explode? I can't imagine other reason for "didn't work", especially since you didn't provide why.

Comment: @Puciek Yes , crushed

Comment: I guess that sarcasm was lost in translation. What was the error message?

Comment: @Puciek http://prntscr.com/4tk8h9

Comment: If you're calling tobytes in the server, why aren't you calling frombytes on the client?

Comment: @Foon That was a mistake , but still not working

Comment: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025675/python-image-frombytes-arguments

Comment: Since you're using port 80, I assume that your server is running with root privileges...

Comment: @AlexKroll I didnt really understand how i need to to that.

Comment: You code say : `data_img = Image.frombytes(data)`, and the error says `data_img = Image.fromarray(data)` when docs says `Image.frombuffer()` ... which version of Python and PIL do you use ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta sry , i updated the error

Comment: @user2697241 read the docs carefully please.
'PIL.Image.frombytes(mode, size, data, decoder_name='raw', *args)'
you miss first argument:

>Parameters: 

>    mode – The image mode.
>    size – The image size.
>    data – A byte buffer containing raw data for the given mode.
>    decoder_name – What decoder to use.
>    args – Additional parameters for the given decoder.

Comment: @AlexKroll didnt worked .. or i did it wrong :
http://prntscr.com/4tnaes

Comment: @user2697241 or you have not read the documentation. 1. Read about ['mode'](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=mode#PIL.Image.mode) (it's not a file format) for example 'mode' can be 'RGB' for jpeg, but I don't know which bytes was sended. 2. 'size' for image is a (width,height). 3. Make sure your client received something sensible.